# Error: Could not find mediaLib accelerator wrapper classes with extension GIS

Tags: java, gis, netlogo

When I run my NetLogo model with extension GIS in Linux, I obtain this error message:

```
Error: Could not find mediaLib accelerator wrapper classes. Continuing in pure Java mode.
Occurs in: com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/medialib/mlib/Image
at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor$1.run(MediaLibAccessor.java:248)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor.setUseMlib(MediaLibAccessor.java:245)
at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor.useMlib(MediaLibAccessor.java:177)
at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor.isMediaLibCompatible(MediaLibAccessor.java:357)
at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor.isMediaLibCompatible(MediaLibAccessor.java:315)
at com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MlibScaleRIF.create(MlibScaleRIF.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory
```

...

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known issue; see https://github.com/NetLogo/GIS-Extension/issues/4

I don't think this error being printed actually affects anything. Is something not working, or are you just concerned about seeing the error message? If the extension seems to work, I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 6):

It's a system property, so you'd have to do it at a system level, i.e. by adding `-Dcom.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib=true` in your **VM Options**.